# How can I reference a boolean variable from an intent (background service)?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a background service `GpxService`:

```
public class GpxService extends Service implements LocationListener {
    public boolean is_recording;
    ...
}
```

I am able to start this service as a background service in my MainActivity:

```
gpxService = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GpxService.class);
gpxService.setAction(GpxService.START_SERVICE);
// notification, startForeground, etc. managed within gpxService onStartCommand
startService(gpxService);
```

**How can I access the flag boolean `is_recording` in the Intent gpxService in the MainActivity?**

---

Background: I have two buttons, *record* and *stop*. In the `onCreate` method of MainActivity, I use `setEnabled` to grey out one and leave the other clickable. I want which button is greyed and which is left clickable to depend on the boolean flag `is_recording` in the background service.

I can't have `is_recording` in MainActivity since it is sometimes destroyed to clear memory. In this case, with the background service still running, reopening the app will reset the `is_recording` flag, triggering the if statement wrongly, and greying out the wrong button.

Comment: Sent a local broadcast  from service ..

Comment: user your GpxService class as IntentService and send your Boolean flag as putExtra using broadcast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cases such as yours, you should be using `IBinder` to establish a connection between the `Service` object and your `Activity` instance.

Take a look at the [bindService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#bindService(android.content.Intent,%20android.content.ServiceConnection,%20int)) call and after establishing the connection you'll be able to access all the public fields and methods of your active `GpxService` instance.

Comment: This seems to be the better practice over broadcasts. I was also able to successfully implement the `IBinder` and access the `public boolean is_recording` in my service from my activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try to solve it by creating an object and access the variables inside the class....
it may work

Answer (score 0):

another idea: try making that service a subclass of mainActivity, tho it dosent sound as a proper way of doing it